# Using a timestamp in milliseconds to generate a countdown timer in days hours mins secs in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, timestamp, momentjs

I am receiving a timestamp in milliseconds which is the reamining time left for an event to start. I need to use that timestamp to build a countdown timer having days , hours , minutes and seconds. I am a beginner to react and javascript. This is what I have tried but, this code does not seem to convert it properly. Can anyone please helpe me understand where I am going wrong and how I can fix this?

```
 const [timeRemaining, settimeRemaining] = useState(props.timeRemaining);
  const [days, setdays] = useState(0);
  const [hours, sethours] = useState(0);
  const [mins, setmins] = useState(0);
  const [secs, setsecs] = useState(0);

  // countdown timer
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!timeRemaining) return;
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      settimeRemaining(timeRemaining - 1);
      setsecs(timeRemaining / 1000);
      setmins(secs / 60);
      sethours(mins / 60);
      setdays(hours / 24);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [timeRemaining]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having 2 issues:

- Convert time incorrectly
- If you pass props is a miliseconds. You should set remain timing sub with 1000 (coordinate with time interval).

  ```
  const [timeRemaining, settimeRemaining] = useState(props.timeRemaining);
   const [days, setdays] = useState(0);
   const [hours, sethours] = useState(0);
   const [mins, setmins] = useState(0);
   const [secs, setsecs] = useState(0);

   // countdown timer
   useEffect(() => {
       if (timeRemaining < 0) return;
       const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
           settimeRemaining(timeRemaining - 1000);


           setsecs(Math.floor((timeRemaining / 1000) % 60));
           setmins(Math.floor((timeRemaining / 1000 / 60) % 60));
           sethours(Math.floor((timeRemaining / 1000 / 60 / 60) % 24));
           setdays(Math.floor((timeRemaining / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24)));
       }, 100);
       return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
   }, [timeRemaining]);
  ```